# Comma in for loop

Tags: zig

Why am I getting this syntax error in Zig?

```
parse_integers.zig:21:18: error: expected ')', found ','
    for (expected, list.items) |exp, actual| {
```

Here is the code (copied and pasted from the Zig home page):

```
const std = @import("std");
const parseInt = std.fmt.parseInt;

test "parse integers" {
    const input = "123 67 89,99";
    const ally = std.testing.allocator;

    var list = std.ArrayList(u32).init(ally);
    // Ensure the list is freed at scope exit.
    // Try commenting out this line!
    defer list.deinit();

    var it = std.mem.tokenize(u8, input, " ,");
    while (it.next()) |num| {
        const n = try parseInt(u32, num, 10);
        try list.append(n);
    }

    const expected = [_]u32{ 123, 67, 89, 99 };

    for (expected, list.items) |exp, actual| {
        try std.testing.expectEqual(exp, actual);
    }
}
```

I have Zig 0.10.1 installed.

I got this error by running:

```
zig test parse_integers.zig
```

Comment: I'm confused but I dont use zig, but you have this: 
  const input = "123 67 89,99";     is this suppose to be a string that can be an array?  cause you only have 1 comma, or is this number 89.99 and you want to magically make a decimal into an integer and the spaces are the separator between numbers?

Comment: I think it's just a string.

Comment: Well the thing is called "parse integers" and you have a string, so it doesn't work.  What happens if you put a comma in between the numbers like 1,2,3,4 ?  Then if it is designed to loop through the string like an array, it will work if it knows to seperate the numbers on the ","

Comment: Again forgive me i dont know zig but this part:
, input, " ,"); 

It seems to be looking to seperate the input by using ", "  which is a number comma and a space is required in between each number.  Can you try to change input like this   "123, 67.  89, 99";  (note a space after each comma)

Comment: I don't know Zig either. But looking at the docs here: https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:mem for `tokenize`, I think that the `" ,"` is an array of delimeters. So I think in this case `tokenize` splits up the string into a list of items separated by either space or comma.

Comment: I see, also nice that Ali figured it out, there is a direct fix for this sort of thing .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

multi-range for loop has introduced in `0.11` (current master)